# How to select div with pseudoelement ::after in testcafe

Tags: css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I need to click on div with pseudo element `::after`.

Div itself is invisible, but after hovering on another element, the `div::after` append icon at the end of div which I need to click.

How can I create a selector for `div::after`?

I can perform click in console with jQuery, but I can't do it in testcafe, because I get

> Error:'actionElementIsInvisibleError'.

Use selector `.more-options::after` is not working

Answer (score 3):

You have to simulate yourself the hovering effect by 'patching' the style of the targeted div. In other words you have to make it visible by calling a client function that will change the div style. You may find a code sample here : [tc-client-function-set-style-attribute](https://github.com/hdorgeval/testcafe-snippets#tc-client-function-set-style-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar challenge with checkboxes

One of the thing I did is to setting the visibility of the element before clicking it.

ex:

```
const consent = ClientFunction(() => {
  document.getElementById("agb").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("datasecurity").style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

then call the function
and then click on the checkboxes.